# Update multiple records for PUT in Rest API

Tags: rest, updates, put

I have an API to update records in my Database. I have the endpoint as below

PUT `/student/name/{name}/roll/{rollNumber}/reg-number/{regNumber}`

and body as

```
{
"studentList" : [
{
      "fathersName": "string",
      "baseSubject": "string",
      "age": "string",
      "preferredLanguage": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

Each record is uniquely identified by the `name`, `rollNumber` and `regNumber` and I want to update multiple records at once (I have a list in my request body).

What is the best way to achieve this? Should I pass arrays of `name`, `rollNumber` and `regNumber` as path param and corresponding records in sequential order in the body inside `studentList`

or

I should have all fields in the body itself and nothing in the path params?

I am following OpenAPI specs.

**Update:** Adding some more details to my question

I have a table with Primary key as a combination of `name`, `rollNumber` and `regNumber`

I want to update multiple rows in a single PUT call. The fields which can be updated are passed in my request body and the fields which are used to identify the row that has to be updated are being passed in the URI as path Params.

I would like to know the correct approach and rest specification to achieve this. The two options which I have in mind have been mentioned in my question.

Comment: The question is unclear. Do you want to update multiple rows with different ```name```, ```roleNumber```, and ```regNumber```? If so, why not add a path ```Put /students``` and send the list in the body?

Comment: That is one approach that I have already mentioned in my question, but what is the correct rest specification for this? I have seen swagger documentation which passes the primary key in the URI as path param and then updates the whatever is received in the request body. Which is fine for a single record update, but what happens when I have to update multiple records? Basically, tell me the right REST spec to do it. Obviously passing everything in the body would work but how would the consumer know what is going to be updated and what is the identifier for a record?

Comment: As one of the few constraints REST puts on the table is caching, you should design the interaction to make use of and support caching. By attempting to perform bulk-operations, you will sooner than later find out that REST isn't ideal for such tasks as you have hardly no tools available to invalidate multiple resources at the same time, especially if you use different URIs to address these resources. Note that the URI is the de facto key used for caching.

Comment: So what should be my approach? Doing one update at a time? If yes, then how do I support the capability of implementing multiple records at a time? because that is what my requirement is